# Remove index.php?_route_ in url and replace it with /

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, url-rewrite-module

Currently I have this on my htaccess but when I go to inner pages of my website the `index.php?_route_` is showing up in the middle of the URL. How can I replace that with `/`?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Right under the `RewriteBase /` line, add:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?_route_=?([^&\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```